# [jQuery]How to get the width of a video from 'loadedmetadata'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the width and the height of a video. In HTML I have:

```
<video id="bg-video" autoplay muted loop src="BG-video/video.mp4"></video>
```

and the CSS is:

```
#bg-video{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

As you can see I didn't specify the width or the height in the CSS or HTML.

I use jQuery to get the width and the height of the video. If the video's resolution is 1364x768 I am expecting to get those values.

I use `loadedmetadata` to be sure that I get the width/height after the video metadata is loaded. This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var videoCache = $('#bg-video'); // this is a video with id="bg-video"
    var foo;
    videoCache.on('loadedmetadata',function(){
        foo = videoCache.width();
        alert('First alert! Width is ' + foo);
    });
    alert('Second alert! Width is ' + foo);
});
```

The problem is that the second alert appears before the the first one and the `foo` value is `undefined` so I can't use the width value outside of the handler. Is there a way to get the right value of `foo` when the second alert appears?

Answer (score 0):

The second alert appears because the first alert is awaiting an event `loadedmetadata` until that occurs, `foo` does not have a defined value.

Anything you wish to occur after that value is set should be run from called from within the `loadedmetadata` event listener.

Comment: I find out that i could use jQuery. deferred https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/
Is this an alternative?

Comment: Not really, you can use it but it's doing the same thing, is there any reason you don't want to use that `loadedmetadata` event? it's the only way you'll know the value is available.